# How to solve the failure to access a proprietary multi-user software in a mapped or shared network drive in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, accessibility, credentials, mapped-drive

I have two desktop computers A (Windows 7 Home premium)and B (Windows 7 Home basic), both using Windows 7.

They are connected to a router. Computer A connects to the router using LAN cable (IPv4 address is 192.168.131.1; subnet mask is 255.255.255.0; no default gateway), whereas computer B connects to the router using wireless connection (IPv4 address is 192.168.0.101; subnet mask is 255.255.255.0; default gateway is 192.168.0.1).

Currently, I have purchased and installed a proprietary multi-user software in in a folder in the C-drive for accounting purpose in computer A. The software comes with a dongle that must be plugged into the computer A to allow the software to work as full-subscription mode.

I did not install the software in computer B. Next, I performed 'map network drive' in computer B, hoping to allow sharing of that specific folder of C-Drive in computer A to the network location of computer B. However, when I tried to access the installed program in computer B, the program appears as a demo version (still until the moment of writing). I can access the installed program in full subscription mode in computer A.

Could this be a program's credential issue? This two windows 7 computer are not connected through home group as for now. Can anyone provide me with advice and suggestion to enable the shared program in the mapped network drive of computer B to access the program in full-subscription mode instead of demo version? Thank you.

Comment: What program is it? This method won't work with most programs. The license is stored somewhere in the registry, user profile or somewhere in %systemdrive%\ProgramData. Relatively, those are machine specific. If the program looks for a license at C:\path, and you run the program from your computer, it looks for a license in C:\path in YOUR computer, and there isn't a license there. A program is not only files, but part of a system, and needs the system. Just executing its exe from a network location is akin to copying its folder, after installation, to another computer, and running it there

Comment: If you want to run it on machineB, then try entering the license when running it from machineB. Might work

Comment: Dear @Dr.Ping, the installed program is called "Aplus accounting". The licence is controlled by the dongle. So, I actually purchased a software and a dongle in a set. Because of poor customer support from Aplus company, I get insights from a business friend who manage to connect two computers running this multi-user Aplus through this "map network drive" method. That is why, I followed his method but I failed. The main reason why I did not insert any licence password or copy any system files from Computer A to computer B because I did not install the software in Computer B. Any advice, Dr?

Comment: Since I don't know this software, and don't know what your friend did, no, dunno what to tell you to achieve that. Can you insert the dongle into computerB when you use the software?

Comment: I tried your step before. When I removed the dongle from Computer A' s CPU, both program appear as demo version in Computers A and B. I manage to visit my friend's office for a while. What he told me of the 'map network drive' seems to be true. I am sure I need some 'networking advice' to achieve what my friend have done.

Comment: Maybe it's a remote session (RDP, TeamViewer etc.), rather than a shared folder?

Comment: Did you 'map' location, or simply added it? Meaning is it mapped as a drive, such as K:?

Comment: Dear @Dr.Ping, i am very sure it is not a remote session. The folder is shared between Computers A and B because I can transfer documents such as pdf files freely across them. Yes, I did map the location of the installed-program containing folder of Computer A' s C-drive into the Computer B's network location, resulting in the formation of M-drive. Do you think i need some 'permission file' to make the program's system files to recognize the feature of fully-subscribed one?

Comment: Why have you got A and B on different subnets? That puts them in different networks.

Comment: @DavidPostill You think that can be the problem here?

Comment: @Dr.Ping Yes. A has no default gateway either ...

Comment: @DavidPostil doh! hadn't thought about that

Comment: @Dr.Ping See the comments on this answer to another of the OPs questions [How to configure the IP address of windows 7 and windows xp through a wireless router to form networking?](https://superuser.com/a/1113119) Something is badly broken with the computer A network config. I just don't know what exactly :)