# How to configure the IP address of windows 7 and windows xp through a wireless router to form networking?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, windows-xp, router

I am writing to seek for technical advice to configure the IP addresses of four computers connecting to a wired/wireless D-Link DI-624 router to form a 'SAME' network for files and printer sharing purposes.

Currently, i have four computers. I would call them computers A, B, C and D despite they have their own computer . The operating details are as follows:

- Computer A: Windows 7 Home premium (IPv4 address is 192.168.131.1; subnet mask is 255.255.255.0; no default gateway).
- Computer B: Windows 7 Home basic(IPv4 address is 192.168.0.101; subnet mask is 255.255.255.0; default gateway is 192.168.0.1).
- Computer C: Windows XP Professional service pack 3 (IPv4 address is 192.168.1.82; subnet mask is 255.255.255.0).
- Computer D: Windows XP Home edition service pack 2 (IPv4 address is 192.168.1.83; subnet mask is 255.255.255.0).

As you may have noticed from the IP address details, only, computer B is using WLAN to connect to the router, while the other computers A, C, and D are all connected to the router through LAN cable. Even though, they are under the same workgroup name which I named as '4in1', they are not entirely connected together under a 'SAME' network. Computer B is not connected to the current network which consists of computers A, C, and D because I can observe all three 'computers' in the network section in their computers.

Since computer B cannot create a Home group with computer A because it is running only in Windows 7 Home basic version, it has not choice but to join computer A's Home group. However, computer A has already formed a network with computers C and D running Windows XP. I say this because I can use the printer shared by computer C to print in computer A and D. One of my questions is how to  allow computer B to form a network with computers A, C and D?

I can only think of a method that may help to achieve the objective above, by configuring the IP address of computer B to join the current network with existing three computers since we have different versions of Windows 7 and XP used. Forming the Home group is not working in this case. However, I do not know how to technically do it? Can anyone help to guide me, please? If anyone has any other methods that is helpful, please recommend and guide me too? Thank you.

Comment: Why have you got A, B and C+D on different subnets? If you configure all 4 devices to use DHCP correctly they will all be on the same network.

Comment: As @DavidPostill states, why aren't you just configuring all devices to "Automatically obtain IP address" and "Automatically obtain DNS" so that all machines get correctly configured by your router...

Comment: Dear @DavidPostill, aren't the subnet mask for all four computers appear to be the same, that is 255.255.255.0? How do you know they are in different subnets? Please advice me.

Comment: @kjyon2 Look at the IP addresses.

Comment: @DavidPostill, for computers A, C and D, is it normal to have no default gateways? However, the network for computers A, C and D is formed. Is it possible for a 'same' network to be formed if the subnets are different for computers A, C, and D?  Do I check whether I did set to use static IP address in my case? What should I do now?

Comment: @kjyon2 No it is not normal to have no default gateway. See the comment above from Big Chris "configure all devices to "Automatically obtain IP address" and "Automatically obtain DNS" so that all machines get correctly configured by your router". Why are you using static IP addresses? That is probably what is causing your PCs to be in different networks.

Comment: @DavidPostill and Big Chris, thank you for your insights. Without setting static IP address, how can we connect windows XP and 7 together in a 'same' network since the new feature of Home group from Windows 7 is not existed in, and, probably, cannot be detected by Windows XP. If none of the side is joining one's group, can the 'same' network or subnet be existed?  However, the workgroup in the systems of all these 4 computers are the same.  Isn't the system's workgroup influenced the status of the subnet whether these computers belong to the same network or subnet? Please advice me.

Comment: @kjyon2 Sigh. See the previous comments. "configure all devices to "Automatically obtain IP address" and "Automatically obtain DNS" so that all machines get correctly configured by your router". Then they will **be in the same network**.

Comment: And then let all PCs join the same workgroup (the name is arbitrary) so you can see their shares in one place in explorer. As soon as they are part of the same physical network (IP addresses from the same network) you can share printers and file shares. You don't need the "home group" feature of Win7 to connect them to each other. Also, not specifying the default gateway on a PC will prevent it to reach the internet. This might be intended or not.

Comment: Dear @user1016274, thank you for explaining the use of default gateway in connecting to the Internet. So far, from my other post and your post, it seems the 'name' of the workgroup influencing the ability to join to the same network is still not clearly understood. Some of them believe in it, but some experienced ones are not because they can manipulate the network settings among different computers to join each other to form a same network or subnet. The subnet referred here is not the subnet mask. I am still learning and this is as far as I can understand.

Comment: Dear @BigChris, after setting to "automatically obtain IP address & DNS, the new details as followed: Computer A: (IPv4 address:192.168.131.1; subnet mask:255.255.255.0; no default gateway).Computer B:(IPv4 address:192.168.0.101; subnet mask: 255.255.255.0; default gateway:192.168.0.1).
Computer C:(IPv4 address:192.168.0,103; subnet mask:255.255.255.0; default gateway:92.168.0.1). Computer D: (IPv4 address:192.168.0.102; subnet mask:255.255.255.0; default gateway:192.168.0.1). Computer A have no default gateway & differenI Ipv4. Is Computer A in the same network as computers B, C and D now?

Comment: Computer A still isn't configured correctly. The others are. B, C and D should all at least be able to ping each other. On a run `cmd` and type `ipconfig  /release` then `ipconfig /renew` and see if A gets am IP similar to B, C and D.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I configure all devices to "Obtain an IP address automatically"?

The following works on all version of Windows from XP onwards.

1. Click the "Start" button.
2. Click on "Control Panel", then "Network and Internet Connections".
3. Click "Network Connections".
4. Right click on "Local Area Connections" and select "Properties".
5. Double-click on the "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)".
6. Select "Obtain an IP address automatically".
7. Select "Obtain DNS server address automatically".
8. Click "OK".
9. Click "OK".

   [image]

Comment: Noted, thank you for your guidance and advice.

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, following your advice, the latest IP details are as followed: Computer A: (IPv4 address:192.168.131.1; subnet mask:255.255.255.0; no default gateway).Computer B:(IPv4 address:192.168.0.101; subnet mask: 255.255.255.0; default gateway:192.168.0.1).
Computer C:(IPv4 address:192.168.0,103; subnet mask:255.255.255.0; default gateway:92.168.0.1). Computer D: (IPv4 address:192.168.0.102; subnet mask:255.255.255.0; default gateway:192.168.0.1). Computer A have no default gateway & different Ipv4 address. Is Computer A in the same network as computers B, C and D now? How do I check?

Comment: "Is Computer A in the same network?" No, other wise it would an IP address of 192.168.0.x and the same gateway as B, C, and D. A is still misconfigured. Are you assigning it a static address in the router? What does it show in the TCP properties dialog for computer A?

Comment: I would like to attach a picture for you, but i find no way to do so. After reaching the TCP dialog box, in the 'General' tab, it has two ticks on 'obtain an IP address automatically' and on 'obtain DNS server address automatically. In the 'alternate configuration' tab, a tick is found in the 'Obtain private IP address'. Is there anything you need to understand my situation?

Comment: @kjyon2 Please turn off all 4 PCs and the router. Turn the router back on, wait 5 minutes and then turn on the computers. Does A then still have IP 192.168.131.1?

Comment: Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share in a comment. Please provide such a link for the computer A configuration screen.

Comment: Dear DavidPostill, I have restart the computer A and get the same IPv4 address. This is the URL link (http://imgur.com/gallery/JeGtv) to the uploaded images regarding the TCP dialog box and the ipconfig result.  Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Is computer A running in a VM?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. To be frank, I have never used VM before. In fact, I even need to Google 'VM' to understand your comment above. I would say I am not using VM. Based on this image (http://imgur.com/gallery/pd0Fc), I am connected to two types of networks. In my Network and sharing center, it seems Computer A is connected to some sort of VM (http://imgur.com/gallery/gfwVi) if i am not mistaken. Please advice me according.

Comment: @kjyon2 I would delete the network connection from computer A and add a new one. Allow Windows to configure it and see what happens. If A is a work computer (it is connected to something called " Work network) then speak to your IT department. Company networks are off-topic.

Comment: do you mean I have to delete both networks (that is, the Work group and the unidentified network) existed in Computer A? Then, I should allow the original network (which could be a default Home group since it is running Windows 7) to configure its IPv4 address with the router, right? Honestly, I do not have a IT department. Previously I hired an IT technician but he had resigned to further his study in Singapore.

Comment: @kjyon2 Yes, that sounds correct.