# How can we map a network drive if we have not established a network among computers running in Windows XP and 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, network-shares, mapped-drive

I am writing to seek advice whether we can map a network drive without previously establishing a network among computers running Windows XP and 7. The network here refers to the local area network (LAN) or wireless local area network (WLAN) linked through a router.

For these LAN and WLAN to be established, besides the use of workgroup among Windows XP, whereas Homegroup among Windows 7, what can be used to establish a 'network' to 
1) allow files, folders, and printers to be shared between Windows XP and Windows 7?; 
2) allow mapping of network drive to be performed?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried signing up to the same Homegroup/Workgroup? Naming it the same? And then actually sharing a directory/folder? I am running Win-7 and utilize a Workgroup. I had XP for years and it was the same, Workgroup. For me they are both Workgroup. However on Win10 it is Homegroup.

Comment: You have already been told how to fix your issue in your previous two questions [How to configure the IP address of windows 7 and windows xp through a wireless router to form networking?](https://superuser.com/q/1113075), and [How to solve the failure to access a proprietary multi-user software in a mapped or shared network drive in windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/1112473). Configure you computers **to be in the same network** and your [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) will go away.